# Short story about children, crows, and language learning

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

While in Covid Quarantine in 2020, I read a short story in which a child starts talking to a mysterious person online when they're supposed to be chatting with their aunt. That person is not a human but a crow or raven that the child's aunt rescued. Because surprise/spoiler, the kid's aunt is working on a language interpreting/teaching AI program and that pesky corvid got into messing with it, like they do.

IIRC, this was told from the point of view of the kid's mom, who is concerned about this mysterious person staying at her sister's place and is constantly telling her kid that they're hungry (or similar simple concerns as the program gets used to speaking Corvid).

Adding/clarifying: I'm not sure the modality, but it's likely a printed anthology, an online magazine, or online podcast. I know it's not AO3, Reddit, or another "informal"(?) online source.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did you read this in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: I read this quite recently. I'm thinking that it was a Chinese author translated into English

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @LogicDictates! I honestly don't remember. And I certainly enjoy all of those forms.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @valorum! IIRC, Clarkesworld has lots of translated stuff. I also was reading quite a bit of Ken Liu's translations, so I'll take a look closer at those in the meantime.

Comment: Might I suggest "corvid quarantine"?

Comment: Har! I was signing in to say the same thing!

Comment: Similar to Annalee Newitz's childrens story [When Robot and Crow Saved East St. Louis](https://slate.com/technology/2018/12/annalee-newitz-short-story-when-robot-and-crow-saved-east-st-louis.html) though unless you've badly misremembered the story there are too many differences for it to be your story.

Comment: @JohnRennie - I *am* very familiar with that story, and I used it for my last professional development series. It's pretty great, and certainly not /just/ for kiddos. The fact it was received so well made me want to seek this story that also has corvid/human interaction as we review/delve into machine learning. I totally recommend it to all people who haven't read it yet.

Comment: @Adamant and occam Shave - Hah, I wasn't sure if I wanted to be that cheesy in my first post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is almost certainly "[Hello, Hello](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1933905)" by Seanan McGuire.  I read it in one of the big annual SF collections (Best New SF or similar) but a quick search led me to a copy in Lightsped magazine.
https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/hello-hello/

It looks like it was printed in quite a few places.

In the plot a child is communicating with someone via their aunt's communication system which is designed to read in typing and gestures and transmit an avatar that speaks.  Eventually it turns out that the communicator is a crow called Pitch and the system is interpreting it's vocalisations and gestures and translating them in to language.

Comment: This is definitely the one that I read.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!